# Parse columns to reshape dataframe

Tags: python, regex, csv, dataframe, reshape

I have a csv that I import as a dataframe with pandas. The columns are like:

```
Step1:A Step1:B Step1:C Step1:D Step2:A Step2:B Step2:D Step3:B Step3:D Step3:E
0         1        2        3       4      5       6       7       8     9
```

Where the step and parameter are separated by ':'. I want to reshape the dataframe to look like this:

```
    Step1   Step2   Step3
A   0          4    nan
B   1          5      7
C   2        nan    nan
D   3          6      8
E   nan      nan      9
```

Now, If I want to maintain column sequential order such that I have this case:

```
Step2:A  Step2:B    Step2:C  Step2:D    Step1:A   Step1:B   Step1:D  AStep3:B   AStep3:D    AStep3:E
0        1          2        3          4         5         6        7          8           9
```

Where the step and parameter are separated by ':'. I want to reshape the dataframe to look like this:

```
    Step2   Step1   AStep3
A   0          4    nan
B   1          5      7
C   2        nan    nan
D   3          6      8
E   nan      nan      9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `read_csv` with `delim_whitespace`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(':', expand=True)
df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

output:

```
   Step1  Step2  Step3
A    0.0    4.0    NaN
B    1.0    5.0    7.0
C    2.0    NaN    NaN
D    3.0    6.0    8.0
E    NaN    NaN    9.0
```

Comment: This works but: 
A) does not keep column sequential order.
B) first line df=pd.read_csv('file.csv')